How to identify the linearly independent rows in an LDPC matrix?
In this example, isn't the number of linearly independent rows 5 (the first 5 rows)? How come there are 13 linearly independent rows? Can we not build any row below using the first 5 rows? Also, how do I calculate the dimension? Sorry, I am totally lost, just started learning this. [LDPC Matrix example]


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No, the first $5$ rows cannot generate the rest of the rows. You can see this by noticing the following. In any (non-zero) linear combination of the first $5$ rows, at least one of the adjacent blocks of four $1$'s will be present. For example, if you include the very first row in the linear combination, the string will start with $1111$ as the other four rows do not have any $1$'s in those positions.
For the dimension of the code, basic knowledge in binary linear codes tells us that the dimension + the number of independent rows in the parity check matrix equals the code length. In this example, the number of independent rows is $13$, and the code length is $20$. Hence, the dimension of the code is $\boxed{7}$.

Ahhh, I understand my mistake now. When I was trying to represent one row in terms of other rows, I was multiplying different constants to each element of a single row. I had to multiply the same constant as I understand now. And the best way to get the number of independent rows is to find the reduced row echelon form, right? I just did it in Matlab and I got 13 independent rows. Thank you very much ~~
